# Can't Multiply Sequence By Non-Int of Type Float? Python

Tags: python, plot

Module OneDMaps:

```
def LogisticMap(a,nIts,x):
    for n in xrange(0,nIts):
        return 4.*a*x*(1.-x)
```

Actual Program:

```
# Import plotting routines
from pylab import *
import OneDMaps 

def OneDMap(a,N,x,f):
    return x.append(f(a,N,x))

# Simulation parameters
# Control parameter of the map: A period-3 cycle
a = 0.98
# Set up an array of iterates and set the initital condition
x = [0.1]
# The number of iterations to generate
N = 100

#function name in OneDMaps module
func = LogisticMap

# Setup the plot
xlabel('Time step n') # set x-axis label
ylabel('x(n)') # set y-axis label
title(str(func) + ' at r= ' + str(a)) # set plot title

# Plot the time series: once with circles, once with lines
plot(OneDMap(a,N,x,func), 'ro', OneDMap(a,N,x,func) , 'b')
```

The program is supposed to call a function from a module OneDMaps.py and then plot it against it's iterates. I get the error "Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float" and i've tried using LogisticMap(float(a)...) but that didn't work. Also I want the function name to show up in the title of the plot but i get "at r=0.98 instead of it saying LogisticMap at r= 0.98.

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? It seems clear to me what the error is. `"Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float"` - this means you can't do `4.*'s'` If you just want to multiply, remove the `.` from `4.*a*x*(1.-x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set up a `list` like this:

```
x = [0.1]
```

You then multipy it by a `float`:

```
return 4.*a*x*(1.-x)
```

You can't do that.  Perhaps you wanted `x` to be an `array` instead of a `list`?

```
x = array([0.1])
```

(That would do the multiplication elementwise)

---

Note that adding lists concatenates:

```
[0] + [1] == [0, 1]
```

Multiplication by an integer is the same as concatenating that many times:

```
[0] * 3 == [0, 0, 0]
```

But that makes no sense for floats,

```
[0] * 3.0 #raises TypeError as you've seen
```

(what should you get if you multiply by 3.5 for example?)

Comment: +1 to you and the OP - I had no idea you could define floats that way :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- define floats what way?

Comment: Using `4.` and omitting the `0` - makes sense but cool nonetheless.

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- Oh that, I would recommend that you use the extra `0` ... `3.0` instead of `3.`.  It makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem :) btw, what's wrong with my title code? It shows the title name but it added a "<function LogisticMap" and some computer address.

Comment: @Randy -- `func` is a function.  Do you want the function's name?  If that's the case, then you want `func.__name__`, or probably better, `func.func_name`